# Why is my search function always outputting true?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

```
let rec contains (x: int list)(y: int) : bool =
begin match x with
| [] -> false
| [y] -> true
| hd::tail -> (hd = y) && (contains tail y)
end
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in my pattern matching but for any non-empty list I input, I keep getting "true" as my return type, when I want it to return true only if the input int exists in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems.
The first is you use pattern matching to check if the list is exactly `[y]`.
This is not how it works, it will actually match any list with exactly one element.
If you want to state equalities like that you can use `when` clauses.

```ml
let rec contains (l : int list) (y : int) : bool =
  begin match l with
  | [] -> false
  | [z] when z = y -> true
  | [z] -> false
  | hd :: tl -> hd = y && contains tl y
  end
```

The first `[z] when z = y` will trigger on a list containing exactly your `y`.
The second clause `[z]` will trigger on the rest.

Then, there is the problem of your last case: `y` belongs to `hd :: tl` if it is `hd` **or** if it belongs in `tl`. You used *and*, so that couldn't be right.
This gives us:

```ml
let rec contains (l : int list) (y : int) : bool =
  begin match l with
  | [] -> false
  | [z] when z = y -> true
  | [z] -> false
  | hd :: tl -> hd = y || contains tl y
  end
```

Of course this can even be simplified.

```ml
let rec contains (l : int list) (y : int) : bool =
  begin match l with
  | [] -> false
  | hd :: tl -> hd = y || contains tl y
  end
```

Indeed there is no need to make a special case of the list with one element.
`[y]` is the same as `y :: []`.

So to sum it up, if the element is in the head you got it, otherwise you go look in the tail, and so on until you reach the empty list which means you didn't find it.

Comment: Ah thank you for that. I am curious though, why is it that it matches every list with one element if I specify in the match that the element should be `y` ? I assumed that it would just link my `y` variable in the match with that in the input of the function, not consider it a generic element.

Comment: There is no way in pattern matching to refer to the variables of the context, except by using `when` clauses. When you write patterns, it's a bit like when writing functions, it **binds** the variables that appear on the left. In your example, if there was some variable named `hd` in your code, it would change the behaviour of the function, so it would become less predictable and compositional.